# How can I fix the 'Token ',' expected' error when using Excel Power Query to post to an API?

Tags: api

I am trying to use excel power query to post data to an api in order to retrieve information.
I have the following:

let

```
Source = Json.Document(
    Web.Contents(
        "https:xxxxxxxxx", 
        [
            Headers=[#"xxxxxxx"="xxxxxxxx",#"Content-Type"="application/json"], 
            Content=Text.ToBinary({"codes" : ["MI3002", "BB1001"]})
        ]


    )
),


// Conver the Results to table.
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),


// Change the Data Types.
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Value", type text}})
```

in

```
#"Changed Type"
```

the xxxxx are actual values in my code

I am getting an error code
Token ',' expected

which is highlighting the : after the word codes in the content. I seem to be missing a comma or maybe some double quotes somewhere but I can't figure out where. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried making all the " into "" but that did not help

Comment: I put the content as a variable and double "" and now there are no syntax errors. However now I get an error when it tries to run:DataFormat.Error: We found an unexpected character in the JSON input.
Details:
    Value=<
    Position=0